# Непонятный отступ в php storm

Tags: phpstorm

При вставке кода в phpstorm первая строка ново вставленного текста съезжает чуть ли не на пол строки, а оставшиеся строки наоборот чуть левее. как убрать эти ненужные реформаты кода IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделите весь текст и нажмите `Ctrl+Alt+L` - тогда `phpstorm` Поставит Вам все отступы одинаковые. А размер отступа Вы можете поменять в настройках самого шторма, или же поставить в корень проекта файл `.jshintrc`, прочитайте в документации, что он может: http://jshint.com/docs/

или на русском: http://dmitrypodgorniy.com/blog/all/s-kodom-bud-strog-nastroyka-jshint/